# Using $.get method to get xml data from asmx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, web-services, asmx

I am trying to use $.get method to get the xml data from this web service:
http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate

I am getting error when i try getting the data.

Sample code:

```
var FromCurrency = "USD";
var ToCurrency = "JMD";
var url = "www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency="+FromCurrency+"&ToCurrency="+ToCurrency;
var jqXHR;

alert(url);
jqXHR = $jQuery.get(url,function(data){
    alert(data);
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });


// Do something here

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqXHR.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can view the error reproduced here with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWW2S/1/

Comment: What would you suggest that I do in this case?

Comment: You are going to have to create a proxy on your own server that relays the data. So basically you create your own service hosted on the same domain as your website that simply passes the calls back and forth between the remote service you want.